# How to automatically update the image in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter, frontend

guys. I have been trying to make a very very basic user interface, where one could see how the images look after being processed (new image every 10 seconds) in another python script. One of the solutions was to get the name of the image from the other script and post it into a txt file. While the script, where im programming the user interface, reads this txt file and gets the image name. I found a few answers here on stackoverflow that all seem to work for other people but dont work for me. My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from subprocess import Popen
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import tkinter.scrolledtext as scrolledtext

tkimg = [None] #tkinter ne osveži slike brez tega
def pic_refresh(): #posodablja sliko na trenutno stanje
    f = open('pics.txt', 'r')
    posnetek_zaslona = f.read()
    tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("./data/" + posnetek_zaslona))
    slika = tk.Label(root, image= tkimg)
    slika.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes") #side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes"
    slika.configure(image= tkimg)
    slika.image= tkimg
    root.update()
    f.close()
    root.after(5000, pic_refresh) # run every 1 seconds

def loop():
    with open("text.txt", "r") as t:
        lbl.insert(INSERT,t.readlines()[-1]) #readlines[-1] prebere samo zandjo vrstico iz txt 
    root.after(15000, loop)

root = tk.Tk()

root.title('Slike neba')
root.geometry('350x150') # Size 200, 200
root.resizable(width=True, height=True)

#definira start in stop funkcijo
def start():
    #file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('Python Files', '*.mp4')])
    filename = askopenfilename()
    filename = filename.split('/')[len(filename.split('/')) - 1]
    print(filename)
    if filename:
        Popen(["python", "najkrajšarazdalja_math.py"])
        loop() #začne z branjem in vpisovanjem vrednosti transparence

def stop():
    print ("Stop")
    root.destroy()

#gumbi
startButton = tk.Button(root, height=2, width=20, text ="Start",command = start)
startButton.pack()
stopButton = tk.Button(root, height=2, width=20, text ="Stop",command = stop)
stopButton.pack()


lbl = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, undo=True)
lbl.pack()

top = Toplevel()
top.geometry("180x100")
top.title("toplevel")

l2 = Label(top, text = "This is toplevel window")
l2.pack()

pic_refresh()
root.mainloop()
```

the function that is supposed to work is called pic_update and is called every time i press the start button or function for that matter. Now when i press start button, which starts running a script called najkrajšarazdalja_math, which takes a screenshot every 10 seconds, i expect the program to refresh the canvas every 10 seconds with the new picture. However, I can only see the first picture and its not updating even tho new screenshots are being made as well as the names of them wirtten into a txt file (pics.txt). Did anyone experience something similair? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Since you create *new label* to show the image whenever `pic_refresh()` is executed, if the image is a fullscreen shot, then those images other than the first image are packed outside the screen because the first image has already occupied the whole screen.  You need to create the label once outside `pic_refresh()` and update the image inside it.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Your solution worked, thank you!